# window.open() does not load the page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I want to open a page in a new window/tab but when it's oppen the page don't load.

**Controller:**

```
public static Result loadCreateArtigo(){
     return ok(request().host()+request().path());
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$.SmartMessageBox({
  buttons : '[Não][Sim]'
}, 
function(ButtonPressed) {
  if (ButtonPressed === "Sim") {            
    Controller.loadCreateArtigo().ajax({
      success: function(data){
          window.open(data);
      },                   
  });
});
```

The var 'data' returns the url. The url is right but the page don't load. Just load if I click F5. I'm using Google Chrome. Some suggestion?

**EDIT:**

I'm testing some possible solutions and i got it: if I put `window.open("www.google.com")`, the new window opens with url like: localhost:9000/"mypath"/www.google.com. I don't know if it could help but...

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: No, the console does not show any error.

Comment: check if pop ups are blocked in the chrome?also can you share what's the value in the data?

Comment: Pop ups was blocked, but i unlock that and i have the same problem :S

Comment: Are you sure that returned `data` is not a javascript object with some property containing url? dump data to console.

Comment: The data in console prints: 'localhost:9000/base/configs/artigos/create'

Comment: try from console window.open('localhost:9000/base/configs/artigos/create');

try also add http:// to url

Comment: should not it contain http/https? try   window.open('http://localhost:9000/base/configs/artigos/create');

Comment: I don't know why, but if I do like that: window.open("http://"+data); it solves my problem. The browser does not recognize the string like an url ?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that if you use a string url as parameter of window.open, it has to be an absolute url, like http://example.com. So be sure that your data is absolute url, else add "http[s]://" before it.
For reference [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/open) about window.open.

Comment: You, sir, deserve a cookie!